# Por que não consigo liberar memória?

Tags: c++, gerenciamento-de-memória

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
#include "iostream"

int main(){

    int* A = new int[4];
    int* B = A;
    delete[] A;
    delete B;

    if(B == NULL)
        std::cout << "B = NULL" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << B << std::endl;

    if(A == NULL)
        std::cout << "A = NULL" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << A << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Pela lógica da linguagem ao chamar a função delete, ele deveria liberar o espaço na memória, sendo assim deveria entrar no laço que faz a conferencia para mim se valor é NULL, porém isso não ocorre.

Alguém sabe me explicar o porque disso?

Comment: Opte por utilizar `#include <iostream>` com `<iostream>` em vez de `"iostream"`. Quando você usa aspas, o compilador vai procurar `iostream` no diretório do seu programa e, como não vai achar, (só então) vai buscar no diretório do sistema.

Comment: Complementando o comentário do Lucas Nunes, utilize aspas duplas para incluir apenas seus arquivos locais. Em relação a sua pergunta, ao utilizar `delete` a memória é liberada mas o conteúdo não é alterado imediatamente. Isso pode causar comportamentos indefinidos. Neste caso, é válido deletar o ponteiro `delete B;` e então definir como nulo `B = NULL;`. Em todo caso, sempre que possível utilize [ponteiros inteligentes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh279674.aspx). Neste [guia](https://github.com/kelvins/Boas-Praticas-Cplusplus) você pode encontrar algumas boas práticas em C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acontece que quando você usa o operador `delete` a memória não é deletada de fato, ela é apenas marcada como "livre" para uso, o ponteiro também não é modificado, é um dever seu atribuir `NULL` ao ponteiro para evitar confusões.

Então ao usar o operador `delete` a memória continua acessível, mas a medida que novas alocações forem sendo feitas vai acontecer que sua memória deletada anteriormente vai ser cedida para outra variável e então seu ponteiro vai estar apontando para um bloco de memória corrompido.

O computador faz isso para ganhar desempenho, se você sabe que aquela memória está "livre" não há porque desperdiçar tempo preenchendo ela com `zeros`. O mesmo esquema é feito em HDs, os  espaços são apenas marcados como vazios mas os dados continuam lá, por isso as vezes é possível resgatar arquivos deletados.

Comment: Obrigado, o que aconteceu é que eu não havia entendido o conceito de alocação e liberação de memória.

Comment: Estritamente falando a memória nem sempre continua acessível. Ao juntar vários blocos marcados como livres, a biblioteca pode decidir devolver a página ao sistema. Assim o processo não poderá mais acessar a memória (acessar = Falha de Segmentação).

Comment: Isso também Guilherme, bem lembrado.

Answer (score 6):

Em primeiro lugar, `delete` libera a memória apontada pelo ponteiro, mas não toca no ponteiro em si. Ele vai continuar a apontar para onde os dados estavam antes.

Analizando seu código temos que `A` vai receber o ponteiro para uma memória recem alocada, uma lista. Em seguida você faz `B` apontar para o mesmo local que `A`. Depois deleta a lista na memoria apontada por `A`,  que é a mesma apontada por `B`. Agora ambos os ponteiros apontam para uma região inválida da memória. Ao tentar executar `delete B` você invoca *undefined behavior*. Qual quer coisa pode acontecer a partir daqui, muito provavelmente [demônios nasais](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Esse problema é geralmente conhecido como *double free* e várias ferramentas de análise de memória podem detectar esse erro no seu programa, como por exemplo o [address sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/). Compilando o seu código com `g++ main.cpp -o main -fsanitize=address` e executando o resultado, tenho a segunte saída:

```
=================================================================
==11122== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting double-free on 0x60040000dff0:
    #0 0x7ff3c90e39da (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.0.0.0+0x119da)
    #1 0x400b89 (/home/guilherme/main+0x400b89)
    #2 0x7ff3c8a29ec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so+0x21ec4)
0x60040000dff0 is located 0 bytes inside of 16-byte region [0x60040000dff0,0x60040000e000)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7ff3c90e3a4a (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.0.0.0+0x11a4a)
    #1 0x400b7d (/home/guilherme/main+0x400b7d)
    #2 0x7ff3c8a29ec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so+0x21ec4)
previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7ff3c90e388a (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.0.0.0+0x1188a)
    #1 0x400b5e (/home/guilherme/main+0x400b5e)
    #2 0x7ff3c8a29ec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so+0x21ec4)
==11122== ABORTING
```

Answer (score 3):

Para começar, o fato de executar `delete[] A;` não tem nenhum efeito sobre o ponteiro A, especificamente, apenas afeta a memória que o sistema alocou e que tem no ponteio A o endereço que foi alocado e muito menos o ponteiro B. Ambos são entidades distintas.
Cabe a você, como boa prática de programação, atribuir **NULL** aos ponteiros que foram liberados.
Já em relação ao ponteiro B, que culpa ele tem de ser simplesmente uma cópia para a área de memória que foi liberada usando outro ponteiro ? Nenhuma.
Neste caso também é sua responsabilidade controlar seu uso, já que por ser uma cópia pode estar apontando para uma área que não faz mais parte do processo.

Comment: Se o compilador suportar C++11 (e/ou estiver configurado para), pode-se utilizar `nullptr` em vez de `NULL`. Só para acrescentar.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode usar as seguintes funções.

```
// C++
template <class T> void SDEL(T*& val)
{
    delete val;
    val = NULL;
}

template <class T> void SDEL_ARRAY(T*& val)
{
    delete[] val;
    val = NULL;
}

// uso
// Ponteiro de arrays
int* my_int = new int[2];
my_int[0] = 100;
my_int[1] = 200;

std::cout << "my_int: " << my_int[0] << ", " << my_int[1] << std::endl;

SDEL_ARRAY(my_int);
```

A primeira é para objetos comuns. A segunda é para `arrays`.

Comment: A checagem se o ponteiro é nulo é desnecessária. O operador `delete` já checa isso também.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser, já atualizei a resposta.